# Apache configuration performance for django

Tags: django, performance, apache, httpd.conf

I have a single Django-project on standard webfaction plan (256mb ram). The average loading time of my website is about 4 seconds. I configured most of the performance tweaks regarding Django (caching, compression, serving static files ...). So I'm only interested in improvements of the Apache configuration. Is 4 sec loading time on a website with 200kb of data, needing about 15 request to load, the limit with webfaction or can I improve this significantly? This is what my httpd.conf looks like right now:

```
ServerRoot "/home/XXXXXX/webapps/XXXXXX/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
#LoadModule headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
KeepAlive Off
Listen 28010
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 15
WSGIDaemonProcess XXXX processes=15 python-path=/.../lib/python2.6 threads=8
WSGIPythonPath /home/XXXX/webapps/XXXXX:/home/XXXX/webapps/XXXXXX/lib/python2.6
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/XXXXXX/webapps/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.wsgi
```

Does something like KeepAlive On increase the performance?
Thanks in advance horndash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, no. KeepAlive and Django do not play well together. To quote from the Django book [here](https://github.com/jacobian-archive/djangobook.com/blob/e39a02a405c2f7fad1164bbd0b88b1b6c39bd587/chapter12.rst):

Turn off Keep-Alive

Keep-alive is a feature of HTTP that allows multiple HTTP requests to be served over a single TCP connection, avoiding the TCP setup/teardown overhead.

This sounds good at first glance, but can actually kill performance of a Django site. If you’re properly serving media from a separate server, each user browsing your site will actually only a page from your Django server every 10 seconds at best. This leaves HTTP servers waiting around for the next keep-alive request, and a idle HTTP server just consumes RAM that an active one should be using.

Comment: thanks tttallis. i played around with the preferences and tested most of them. your are right. keepalive and django do not play well together!

Comment: Is KeepAlive Off still a valid option today?